# How to chain multiple java method calls in a single statement?

Tags: java

I am trying to make something that
Instead of having to do

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();

myclass.params(url,body);
myclass.request(); 
myclass.response();
```

to call the functions inside that class

I want it to be like

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();

myclass.params(url,body).request().response();
```

if that is even possible.

Comment: yes, each method just has to return `this` as `MyClass param(...) {...return this;}` and you can chain the calls. But in the end this will probably make your code way more difficult to read.

Comment: Whats wrong with the first approach?

Comment: if `params(url,body)` returns object of `MyClass` then you can call `request()` and same as if `request()` returns the object of `Myclass` then you can call `response()`.

Comment: So Basically the first method is better?

Comment: @Guy depends how you define better, but the second one can yield in some hard to read code pretty fast depending on how often you do chain the calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid question, and yes: it is possible.

The type of api style is called *Fluent interface*. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fluent_interface&oldid=777629642):

> A fluent interface is normally implemented by using method cascading (concretely method chaining) to relay the instruction context of a subsequent call

To implement this for your use case, just declare your methods like this:

```
public MyClass params(String url, String body) {
    // your code here
    return this;
}
```

instead of that:

```
public void params(String url, String body) {
    // your code here
}
```